# Wrong value when copying from global to private memory

Tags: opencl, gpgpu, opencl-c

I am currently learning OpenCL and I have this kernel that works just fine when directly accessing the global array, but gives wrong results when using an intermediate value on the private memory, for example, *aux* on the code below.

```
__kernel void kernel_cte(__global float *U0,__global float *U1,__constant float *VP0, uint stride, uint nnoi, __constant float *g_W, uint k0, uint k1, float FATMDFX, float FATMDFY, float FATMDFZ) {

uint index = get_global_id(1)*nnoi + get_global_id(0) + k0 * stride;

uint k;
float aux;
aux = U0[index+1];

for(k=k0;k<k1;++k) {
    if(VP0[index] > 0.0f){
      U1[index] = 2.0f * U0[index] - U1[index]
        + FATMDFX * VP0[index] * VP0[index] * (
          + g_W[6] * (U0[index - 6] + U0[index + 6])
          + g_W[5] * (U0[index - 5] + U0[index + 5])
          + g_W[4] * (U0[index - 4] + U0[index + 4])
          + g_W[3] * (U0[index - 3] + U0[index + 3])
          + g_W[2] * (U0[index - 2] + U0[index + 2])
          + g_W[1] * (U0[index - 1] + aux)
          + g_W[0] * U0[index]
        )
        + FATMDFY * VP0[index] * VP0[index] * (
          + g_W[6] * (U0[index - 6 * nnoi] + U0[index + 6 * nnoi])
          + g_W[5] * (U0[index - 5 * nnoi] + U0[index + 5 * nnoi])
          + g_W[4] * (U0[index - 4 * nnoi] + U0[index + 4 * nnoi])
          + g_W[3] * (U0[index - 3 * nnoi] + U0[index + 3 * nnoi])
          + g_W[2] * (U0[index - 2 * nnoi] + U0[index + 2 * nnoi])
          + g_W[1] * (U0[index -     nnoi] + U0[index +     nnoi])
          + g_W[0] * U0[index]
        )
        + FATMDFZ * VP0[index] * VP0[index] * (
          + g_W[6] * (U0[index + 6 * stride] + U0[index - 6 * stride])
          + g_W[5] * (U0[index + 5 * stride] + U0[index - 5 * stride])
          + g_W[4] * (U0[index + 4 * stride] + U0[index - 4 * stride])
          + g_W[3] * (U0[index + 3 * stride] + U0[index - 3 * stride])
          + g_W[2] * (U0[index + 2 * stride] + U0[index - 2 * stride])
          + g_W[1] * (U0[index +     stride] + U0[index -     stride])
          + g_W[0] * U0[index]
        );
    } // end if
    index += stride;
}
}
```

I would like to use vectors to perform these calculations but I can't understand why the correct value isn't copied to the private memory when I do aux = U0[index+1].

Comment: I found the problem and it was very obvious, the reading aux = U0[index+1] should be performed inside the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

If each workitem is working on its own dataset, only thing they need is to commit global memory operations with a fence if they are using them and altering them multiple times in same kernel.

For example, `U1[index]` in code below needs committing to global memory if it is not meant to be cached.

```
mem_fence(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);
if(VP0[index] > 0.0f){
      U1[index] = 2.0f * U0[index] - U1[index]
        + FATMDFX * VP0[index] * VP0[index] * (
          + g_W[6] * (U0[index - 6] + U0[index + 6])
          + g_W[5] * (U0[index - 5] + U0[index + 5])
          + g_W[4] * (U0[index - 4] + U0[index + 4])
          + g_W[3] * (U0[index - 3] + U0[index + 3])
          + g_W[2] * (U0[index - 2] + U0[index + 2])
          + g_W[1] * (U0[index - 1] + aux)
          + g_W[0] * U0[index]
        )
        + FATMDFY * VP0[index] * VP0[index] * (
          + g_W[6] * (U0[index - 6 * nnoi] + U0[index + 6 * nnoi])
          + g_W[5] * (U0[index - 5 * nnoi] + U0[index + 5 * nnoi])
          + g_W[4] * (U0[index - 4 * nnoi] + U0[index + 4 * nnoi])
          + g_W[3] * (U0[index - 3 * nnoi] + U0[index + 3 * nnoi])
          + g_W[2] * (U0[index - 2 * nnoi] + U0[index + 2 * nnoi])
          + g_W[1] * (U0[index -     nnoi] + U0[index +     nnoi])
          + g_W[0] * U0[index]
        )
        + FATMDFZ * VP0[index] * VP0[index] * (
          + g_W[6] * (U0[index + 6 * stride] + U0[index - 6 * stride])
          + g_W[5] * (U0[index + 5 * stride] + U0[index - 5 * stride])
          + g_W[4] * (U0[index + 4 * stride] + U0[index - 4 * stride])
          + g_W[3] * (U0[index + 3 * stride] + U0[index - 3 * stride])
          + g_W[2] * (U0[index + 2 * stride] + U0[index - 2 * stride])
          + g_W[1] * (U0[index +     stride] + U0[index -     stride])
          + g_W[0] * U0[index]
        );
mem_fence(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);
```

because either GPU out-of-order instruction execution capability or compiler can reorder reads/writes without asking and fence/barrier is stopping them doing that and keeps order the way developer needs.

If workitems are meant to alter each others data region, then at least barrier() is needed and this works only inside of each block(workgroup).

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem and it was very obvious, the reading aux = U0[index+1] should be performed inside the for loop.